# jQuery variable on switch case returns undefined while in another case returns value, even though variable is declared outside the switch

Tags: jquery, html, variables, switch-statement

I want to be able to display a message in html with two dynamic values declared as variables with a switch statement.

The switch statement displays the message with the two values when those are called separately on every case but when I put them all together in the second case, first value returns undefined.

I need both variables to have their values in the last case so I can put them together in the same html element and not in two elements as it happens right now.

[JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/puzzledGalore/ptv22kq8/19/)

HTML code:

```
<fieldset>
<legend>GROUP A:</legend>
<div class="check-fieldset fieldset-group-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="BRAZIL" class="group1"      id="BRA" />
<label for="BRA">BRAZIL </label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="CROATIA" class="group1" id="CRO" />
<label for="CRO">CROATIA </label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="MEXICO" class="group1" id="MEX" />
<label for="MEX">MEXICO </label>
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="country" value="CAMERUN" class="group1" id="CMR" />
<label for="CMR">CAMERUN </label>
<br />
<div class="alert-group-1"></div>
<div class="alert-group-1b"></div>
<div class="alert-group-all" style="color:red"></div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.check-fieldset input').click(function() {
if ($(this).parents('.check-fieldset').find('input:checked').length >=    2) {
 $(this).parents('.checkfieldset').find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop("disabled", true);
  $(this).siblings('.hide');
  } else {
  $(this).parents('.check-fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop("disabled", false);}});

function marcarSeleccions(checkBoxes, alertofGroup, alertofGroupb) {
var limit = 2;
var selected =   checkBoxes.parents('.checkfieldset').find('input:checked').length;
var count = limit - selected;
var first = checkBoxes.filter('.first').val();
var second;
if (checkBoxes.prop('checked')) {
switch (count) {
case 1:
{
checkBoxes.removeClass('first');
first = checkBoxes.val();
checkBoxes.addClass('first');
alertofGroup.html(first + " classifies first");
}
break;
case 0:
{
second = checkBoxes.val();
alertofGroupb.html(second + " classifies second");
$('.alert-group-all').html(first + " classifies first, " + second + " classifies second");
}
break;
case 2:
{
second = "";
first = "";
alertofGroup.html(first + "");
alertofGroupb.html(second + "");
}
}
};
};

// checkboxes click events
// group A
$('.group1').on('click', function() {
marcarSeleccions($(this), $('.alert-group-1'), $('.alert-group-1b'));
});
});
```

Comment: I've never put `{}` after my `case` statements before.  Does that actually work?

Comment: Yes it does, but you are actually right, better without them.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that when you invoke click event on the element with class `'group1'`, you were passing the current element `$(this)` which was clicked, not the whole collection of items.
So your declaration : `var first = checkBoxes.filter('.first').val();` becomes invalid.

I guess in order to append multiple elements with the same class, just pass the whole collection of items via  `marcarSeleccions($('.group1'), $('.alert-group-1'), $('.alert-group-1b'), $('.first-group1'), $('.second-group1'));`

UPDATED:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  // Set maximum number of selected checkboxes on fieldsets to two, disable rest
  $('.check-fieldset input').click(function() {
    if ($(this).parents('.check-fieldset').find('input:checked').length >= 2) {
      $(this).parents('.check-fieldset').find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop("disabled", true);
      $(this).siblings('.hide');
    } else {
      $(this).parents('.check-fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
  // Retrieval of first and second classified by every fieldset
  function marcarSeleccions(checkBoxes, alertofGroup, alertofGroupb) {
    var limit = 2;
    var selected = checkBoxes.parents('.check-fieldset').find('input:checked');
    var count = limit - selected.length;
    var first = selected.eq(0).val();
    var second = selected.eq(1).val();    
    $('.alert-group-all').html("");
  //  if (checkBoxes.prop('checked')) {
      switch (count) {
        case 1:
          {            
            alertofGroupb.html("");
            checkBoxes.removeClass('first');
            checkBoxes.addClass('first');
            alertofGroup.html(first + " classifies first");
          }
          break;
        case 0:
          {
            alertofGroup.html(first + " classifies first");
            alertofGroupb.html(second + " classifies second");
            $('.alert-group-all').html(first + " classifies first, " + second + " classifies second");
          }
          break;
        case 2:
          {
            alertofGroup.html("");
            alertofGroupb.html("");

          } break;

   //   }
    };
  };
  // checkboxes click events
  // group A
  $('.group1').on('click', function() {
    marcarSeleccions($('.group1'), $('.alert-group-1'), $('.alert-group-1b'), $('.first-group1'), $('.second-group1'));
  });
  // end document js
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ptv22kq8/11/

Comment: This only works the first time you initialize the variables.

Comment: I'm sorry but i did not understand what you meant by "first time you initialize the variables"

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer however the purpose of the checkboxes value detection is to function for each and every one of them on this particular fieldset which is not the case in your fiddle example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ptv22kq8/6/) when user checks other values apart from the first one "BRAZIL". I Appreciate your approach anyway.

Comment: @DinoMyte - the first time you assign values to the checkboxes, it works fine and the values are detected.  But they are no longer detected when you uncheck and check new boxes.

Comment: I'm sorry but that does not happen to me when I check other checkboxes rather than the first one. Values are not shown on the alert html element.

Comment: I figured out some logic issue. Fixed it in the solution and fiddle. check out the updated one.

Comment: Thank you DinoMyte. I think this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the selections in an array and use that to determine what to display in the messages:

https://jsfiddle.net/jh3u9z5b/

```
$('.check-fieldset input').click(function() {

    var $group = $(this).parents('fieldset'),
      result = $group.data("result") || [],
      maxcheck = $group.data("maxcheck");

    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
      result.push($(this).val());
    else
      result.splice(result.indexOf($(this).val()), 1);

    $group.data("result", result);

    if (result.length >= maxcheck) {
      $group.find(':checkbox:not(:checked)').prop("disabled", true);
      $(this).siblings('.hide');
    } else {
      $(this).parents('.check-fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });



function marcarSeleccions($group, alertofGroup, alertofGroupb) {
    var result = $group.data("result") || [],
          resultlen = result.length;

    alertofGroup.html(resultlen > 0 ? result[0] + " classifies first" : "");
    alertofGroupb.html(resultlen > 1 ? result[1] + " classifies second" : "");
    $('.alert-group-all')
        .html(resultlen > 1 ? result[0] + " classifies first, " + result[1] + " classifies second": "");

  };


  $('#group1').on('click', function() {
    marcarSeleccions($(this), $('.alert-group-1'), $('.alert-group-1b'));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you Malk, this seems to do the trick, even though I still think there are too many lines of code for such a simple functionality. I guess there should be a workaround but I find this answer valuable enough.